# What fixture would give the best light in this high-ceiling room?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

My high-ceiling living room has only 3 plug-in lamps, but there are two live, switched electrical boxes on the wall, a few feet apart, just above top of the bookcase in the photo below.

The easiest place to put fixed light fixtures is on the wall immediately over the bookcase.

What type of light fixture might provide the best light for the room, if put on the wall above the bookcase?  (By best, I mean general light throughout the room.)

[image]

Comment: I agree with jsotola, but I'd use a couple of upward-facing sconce lights (mounted to the boxes) or standing lamps (plugged into those boxes via outlets). Light off the ceiling would distribute well.

Comment: @isherwood I just searched for upward-facing sconce lights. All I find is lights that shine both up and down. Can you point me to upward-facing sconce lights?

Comment: @jsotola I tried to clarify the type of lighting I am looking for.  Any suggestions on how to better describe lighting?

Comment: **Uplight wall sconce** finds plenty of results that go only up, mixed with some that go up and down, for me. Whether they suit your taste is up to you. I've thought about converting the standing uplight lamps you have in the right foreground (particularly now that there are LED replacements for those hot, hot, halogens) to wall sconces, but never gotten to that project.

Comment: use the lamp in the right side of the picture to determine if indirect lighting is desirable for you

Comment: install low voltage cable lights ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cable+lights&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: I would run LED strip on top of your bookcase, reflecting off the ceiling like a bounced flash.

Comment: I would think that any lighting along the wall only (as you'd have with plug in lamps or wall sconces) would feel inadequate for reading or a more "formal" type of gathering. That looks like a reasonably large room and the limited amount of light those would cast would simply be lost reflecting off the ceiling. I think manassehkatz's answer for installing ceiling mounted lighting is the way to go.

Comment: That's just the kind of room that halogen torchiere plug-in lights were built for, but unfortunately those things were power hogs and fire-starters (and at 500W, 4 would trip the breaker lol).  I certainly hope that one isn't a real torchiere and is LED or something.  Unfortunately every torchiere replacement I've ever seen puts out FAR less light than 7000 lumens, but that's a costing choice made by the builders because 7000 lm of LED is a little bit of money. (not a LOT).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica And the cheap torchiere makers probably figure (and generally correctly) that a lot of people used them dimmed anyway - if 98% of the people don't compare light output before buying and 50% of those are totally OK with it and most of the rest mutter/complain to random people on the internet but don't actually return the product, then they keep on selling.

Answer (score 3):

Non-trivial solution, but I would look at running a wire up the wall to the ceiling and over to the beam and either hang a chandelier from the middle of the beam, or install track lighting on the beam. You can use moulding along the beam to cover up a wire there so nobody will notice it (I did that for my living room which is now my dining room). If you do it right, you will only need to cut & patch two small sections of the wall/ceiling - one directly above the existing box and one next to the beam.

Comment: I was thinking similarly. Perhaps a valance box around the perimeter with strip lighting would create enough general area lighting. Creates a new look! https://www.coving-cornice.co.uk/ledcoving.html